# Swagger UI not adding headers to request in node js

Tags: node.js, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm facing an issue with Swagger UI where the headers specified in the Swagger documentation are not being added to the request. Specifically, I have an endpoint for user logout, and I'm trying to include the Authorization header using the Bearer token. However, despite defining the header in the Swagger documentation, it is not included in the Swagger UI request. here is the YAML.

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/v1/users/auth/logout:
 *   post:
 *     tags:
 *       - Logout
 *     summary: Logout user
 *     description: Logout user from the system
 *     requestBody:
 *       required: true
 *       content:
 *         application/json:
 *           schema:
 *             type: object
 *             properties:
 *               phoneNumber:
 *                 type: string
 *                 description: User phone number
 *                 example: +201026984193
 *             required:
 *               - phoneNumber
 *     parameters:
 *       - in: header
 *         name: Authorization
 *         description: Bearer token for authentication
 *         required: true
 *         schema:
 *           type: string
 *         example: Bearer ERxoQss46UzGt0SAO0oZO7DykNT4KMvlKqJFcwctFt5DrjyBgCpi9l8H54SuoFlU
 *     responses:
 *       '400':
 *         description: Phone number is required
 *       '401':
 *         description: Phone number is not valid
 *       '404':
 *         description: User not found
 *       '204':
 *         description: User logged out successfully
 *       '409':
 *         description: Missing token
 *       '403':
 *         description: Unauthorized
 *       '406':
 *         description: Missing token and/or phoneNumber
 *       '405':
 *         description: Unauthorized
 *       '500':
 *         description: Internal server error. Something went wrong on the server.
 *       '429':
 *         description: Too many auth requests, please try again later.
 */
```

here is my swagger config file

```
const swaggerJsdoc = require("swagger-jsdoc");
const swaggerUi = require("swagger-ui-express");
const ip = require("ip");
const fs = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config();

const options = {
    definition: {
        openapi: "3.0.0",
        info: {
            title: "",
            description: "",
            version: "1.0.0",
        },
        servers: [
            {
                // url: `http://${ip.address()}:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`,
                url: `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT || 3000}`,
            },
        ],
        security: [{ Authorization: [] }],
    },
    apis: ["./routes/*.js"],
    customCss: `
        .swagger-ui .topbar-wrapper svg {
            display: none;
        }
    `,
};
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJsdoc(options);
const customCss = fs.readFileSync(process.cwd() + "/swagger.css", "utf8");

function swaggerDocs(app, port) {
    app.use(
        "/docs",
        swaggerUi.serve,
        swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec, { customCss })
    );
}
module.exports = swaggerDocs;
```